# Trigger a click on anchor tag with specifc div class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In short, there are two different divs with different classes having anchor tags inside. I want to auto click / trigger clicks on specific anchor tags. Here is my HTML code below.

```
<div class="findme active">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1">link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">link2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="findmetwo active">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1">link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">link2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

For example, I want to auto click on document reload for div with class `findme` click on link1, and for div with class `findmetwo` click on link2. I already added active class to all divs by jquery.

Comment: You need to add onload event listener on document. In that event listener call `element.click()` to simulate click on respective HTML element. Read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

Comment: this is only for , if we focus the mouse pointer over the field or div

Comment: Check answer, if useful, accept it as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching & some RND i was able to reach the solution , here below is the answer of my question

```
jQuery( ".findme3" ).find( ".reviews_tab " ).children('a').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
// similar to document onload
$( document ).ready(function() {
    
    $('.findme li:nth-child(1) a').click();
    $('.findmetwo li:nth-child(2) a').click();    
    
});
```

Check this https://jsfiddle.net/xLyh0o7q/

Comment: if you want to run it only on reload (not on first load of page), use `beforeunload` event listner and set some variable in localstorage which you can check later in onload / ready event listener.

Comment: well i was able to figure out the solution thanks anyway for the help,